# how to write a shell scipt to compress a file from .csv to .tar.gz?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to compress a CSV file to a `.tar.gz` archive.

I tried like this, but its not working. Can any one help on this?

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

LOG_FILES="/tmp/"

for file in $LOG_FILES;
do
   if [ -e "$file" ]
   then
       tar -cvzf $file.tar.gz $file;
   fi
done
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you edit your post to tell us _how_ it is not working? Is there an error message? If so, please post it.

Comment: You will likely find a (hidden) file named `.tar.gz` inside the `/tmp/` directory ...

Comment: in /tmp / folder filename called as express_123.csv , we need to compress that .csv file to (express_123.tar.gz) in the same directory (/tmp/) using script.

Comment: put `echo` in front of `tar -czvf ...` to see what happens...

Comment: output is: tmp.tar.gz
but we need to compress file, not directory

Comment: How is a tar.gz archive containing one file considered better than a plain .gz file?: `gzip *.csv`;

Comment: What type of Unix are you on?

Comment: It is further unclear what you need a loop for if you want to compress "a CSV file", and why you need to compress this single file into a `tar` archive rather than just a `.gz` file.

Comment: now we need to delete .csv file after compressing the file(.tar.gz) .Only .csv file has to remove

Comment: Again, gzip replaces the input file with the .gz anyway, which simplifies some more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` will do it

```
find /tmp/ -type f -name "*.csv" -execdir tar --remove-files -cvzf "{}.tar.gz" "{}" \;
```

This will compress and store files in the same directory of original
file.

This also assumes that you are using GNU `tar`.

Comment: This is working Perfect....Thanks a lot.

Comment: `{}` does not need to be quoted, `find` takes care of it.

Comment: after convertion of .csv to .tar.gz , we need to delete the Original file (.csv file)..Please help.

Comment: ```--remove-files``` flag will do the job. answer updated.

Comment: we need to remove only .csv file from /tmp/.
NOT .tar.gz file from /tmp/

Comment: that what it does...    you can check man page ```tar```

Comment: @pLumo  ```man find``` says  ```Notice
       that the braces are enclosed in single quote marks to protect them
       from interpretation as shell script punctuation.  The semicolon is
       similarly protected by the use of a backslash, though single quotes
       could have been used in that case also.```

Comment: answer updated. @dsl

Comment: i tried , but the .csv file is not removing,

Comment: The fact it says `command not found` and not `invalid option` suggests you have a line-break somewhere earlier in the command ,or missed out the `tar` command word.

Comment: However, `rm *.csv` as the last command will remove all .csv files in the directory. It does seem to me that the answer you accepted will recurse down the /tmp tree (or more likely, fail on permissions): my distro has 7 system directories in there.

Answer (score 1):

1. You want to loop over `/tmp/*.csv` or `"$LOG_FILES"/*.csv` instead of `/tmp/`.
2. You should use `[ -f "$file" ]` to check for **regular** files only ([see](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html))
3. Always quote filename variables: `"$file"`